# how to send server-side source code in Flutter (Code Push)

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, code-push

Is it possible to write a flutter code and save it inside server and then send it to a flutter application and implement this code .. Is this possible?

You can take a look at this:

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_code_push

I tried a lot of things and got this package, but I couldn't use it on Windows devices.

flutter_code_push 1.0.2

Comment: Can you explain bit more about your intent? What exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to write the code on a server and then send it to an application and it will be executed. This is how I can bypass the approval of Google and Apple and solve problems at high speed

Comment: Now WhatsApp and Facebook are working in a push code, But this is supported by react native language.

Comment: I don't remember but **Isolate.spawnUri** can execute compiled **aot-snapshot** or **jit-snapshot**

Comment: this is incompatibale

Answer (score 0):

Might be what you want.

**Isolate.spawnUri** can run compiled code.

https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/50158

Comment: Do you accept the Flutter code?